# getElementById() returns null although element exist

Tags: javascript, html

This is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Demo</title>
  <script>
    function show()
    {
      var content = document.getElementById("content");
      var sub = content.getElementById("sub1");
      alert(sub.nodeName);
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="content">
  <div id="sub1">
    Content 1
  </div>
  <div id="sub2">
    Content 2
  </div>
  <input type="button" value="Click" onclick="show()" />
</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Why don't the content.getElementById and alert functions work? Thank for answer.

Comment: Because there is no `sub1` id. You could do `console.log(sub)` and discover what happens. Or just look at your JavaScript console, it would tell you that `sub` is `null`.

Comment: Just to be clear `class` (`document.getElementsByClassName()`) !== `id` (`document.getElementById()`).

Comment: Why do you get `content` in the first place?  Since ids should be unique, you can use `document.getElementById` for any id.  There's no need to "narrow it down" like that.

Answer (score 9):

You have a class of `sub1`, no ID of `sub1`

Change

```
<div class="sub1">
```

To

```
<div id="sub1">
```

Also change:

```
var sub = content.getElementById("sub1");
```

To:

```
var sub = document.getElementById("sub1");
```

Comment: thank, but it still doesn't work, this is error TypeError: content.getElementById is not a function

Comment: See edited answer, `var sub = content.getElementById("sub1");` is the problem issue.

Comment: @loithuxua: `getElementById` is a function of the `document` object.

Comment: @FelixKling as you say, some_element.getElementByid will no work?

Comment: @loithuxua: Yes. Since IDs are supposed to be unique in the document, there is no need to give every element this method.

Comment: @FelixKling thank you, Do W3C explain this problem?

Comment: @loithuxua: You can have a look at the [`Document` interface definition](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/core.html#i-Document) and the [`Element` interface definition](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/core.html#ID-745549614). [Here is the definition of the ID attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/global.html#adef-id).

Answer (score 0):

Use `var sub = content.getElementById("sub1");` 
Remember the E,B and I are capital letters

And use `alert(sub.innerHTML);`